# How can I preview all of my video strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video, timeline

I have pressed something, not sure what... and now I cannot preview all of the strips in my video, eg; I can preview sound, but not image. If I add a new clip, then this previews fine.

The strips I can't preview seem to be faded out in the video sequence editor, how do I get it back? see image!

Thank you in advance for your help :)

[image]

Comment: Can we get full interface in image?

Comment: [H] to hide selected clips. [Alt H] to unhide selected clips.

Comment: Select your transparent strips and unhide them. Alt+H.

Answer (score 1):

Just select the faded strips and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and the hidden strips i.e your transparent strips, will be unhidden. You probably pressed <kbd>H</kbd> which is used to hide.

Comment: The screenshot looks just like he hid all his strips, so your answer won't help. He has to just select his movie strips and unhide (ALT+H)...

Comment: @Samooth thanks for letting me know, should I edit my answer with yours or you are answering?

Comment: You can answer that, that's fine for me ;-)

Comment: @Samooth I have edited my answer, but if I missed something you can edit further!